# using Meteor to display a collection with headers not known beforehand

Tags: json, templates, meteor

Showing a collection of static known fields is basic to Meteor
where known fixed document key field names are placed in an html template.

However if all the field names are to be found at the time the
data is inserted,then the basic Meteor rendering cannot be used.

Is there any way to publish all the fields which are found by
parsing the json tabulated data ?

Perhaps Houston is the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to return *keys* as values along with the actual values. For example:

```
{{#each kvp object}}
  key: {{key}}
  value: {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

With a helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers(function(){
  kvp: function(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return {key: k, value: obj[k] });
  }
});
```

That assumes an object with no nesting.

`Object.keys(obj)` gives you an array of *keys*. The `map` function then loops over each of those keys. In the mapping function we build a new object from the key and value. The end result is an array of objects that can be looped over in Blaze.

Comment: I'm now tempted to go see if Meteor templates can be used recursively!

Comment: So #each is used to expand horizontally by breaking each document into document/objects of one field, returning a cursor.  I will post the code when it works. It seems many would want such code to easily render a new collection of unknown fields in the documents.

Comment: To do it right you'd want to be able to traverse a hierarchy. This is just a simple solution for a _flat_ object. Also technically it returns an array of objects, not a cursor.

Comment: this works Template.documentItem.helpers({

 item_document: function () {
   console.log(this);
var obj = this;
   return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return {key: k, value: obj[k] }});
   
  }



});

Comment: If your object is `this`, sure.